# Sitemesh does not decorate returned view

Tags: spring-mvc, sitemesh

I have consult [Sitemesh does not decorate returned views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724791/sitemesh-does-not-decorate-returned-views), but this post does not work for me.

I hope sitemesh only decorate `.jsp` pages, but when one view is returned by a controller, it is not decorated.

This is part of my `web.xml`:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

This is my `decorators.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<decorators>
    <decorator name="basicLayout" page="/WEB-INF/decorators/base_layout.jsp">
        <pattern>*.jsp</pattern>
    </decorator>
</decorators>
```

I use `InternalResourceViewResolver` to resolve my view from logic name to actual path:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
    p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

And this is my Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping("/user/registration")
    public String registrationForm() {
        return "user/registration";
    }   
}
```

My `jsp` page is `/WEB-INF/jsp/user/registration.jsp`. After I request `user/registration`, that jsp page comes without any decoration.

Comment: What about your `sitemesh.xml` file?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I don't have a `sitemesh.xml`

Comment: Did you include `decorators.xml`?

Comment: @Alex, yes. If a page is not returned as a view, it can be decorated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your pattern to

```
<pattern>/*</pattern>
```

The path in the pattern is matched again the request path, not the internal `RequestDispatcher#forward()` done with the view name by the `InternalResourceViewResolver`.

You can make your `SiteMeshFilter` only work on `forward` requests though, with

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Yes, this can work. But I only hope `jsp` page to be decorated. Because I also have a RESTful interface have returns `json`.

Comment: @FANGYishu See my edit. Set the `dispatcher` for the `Filter`.